# Java: Formatting nested loops?

Tags: java, loops, nested

I am pretty new to Java and I wanted to make a staircase effect using loops, but adding an increasing amount of spaces to the string as you go down each row.
Heres my code-

```
        for(int i = size; i>0; i--) {
            for(int k = 1; k>size-1; k++) {
                output+=" ";
            }
            for(int j = i; j>0; j--) {
                output+=let;    
            }
            output+="\n";
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Ultimately the goal is to have it print this:

```
22222
 2222
  222
   22
    2
```

But mine prints this:

```
22222
2222
222
22
2
```

I'm sorry, I know this is beginner stuff but I don't know where else to go. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the first inner loop should loop `size - i` times.

Comment: Your second for-loop ``int k = 1; k>size-1; k++``, it should be ``k < size``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `size - i` spaces each time, so change `for(int k = 1; k>size-1; k++) {` to `for(int k = 0; k<size-i; k++) {`.

```
for(int i = size; i>0; i--) {
    for(int k = 0; k<size-i; k++) {
        output+=" ";
    }
    for(int j = i; j>0; j--) {
        output+=let;    
    }
    output+="\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks so much man. Im really new to this stuff. your really helping me learn!

Comment: @Lpatten2905 No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
        int size=5;
        for(int i = size; i>0; i--) {
            for(int k = size-i; k>0; k--) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int j = i; j>0; j--) {
                System.out.print("2");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

your second for loop condition is wrong.
convert `for(int k = 1; k>size-1; k++)`into `for(int k = size-i; k>0; k--)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
      { 
         for(int j = 2 * (n-i); j >= 0; j--) 
         {           
            System.out.print(" "); 
         } 
         for(int j = 0; j<=i; j++) 
         {       
            System.out.print("2 "); 
         }           
         System.out.println();
      }
```

- Note that the int `n` is the number of lines you want to print
- `n = 5` -> 5 lines